# How to print the name and URL of my CLI project separately

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, screen-scraping

I'm building a guitar-browsing CLI. I put the name and URL of the guitar in an array of hashes:

```
def self.get_electric
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://reverb.com/c/electric-guitars"))

        electrics = []
        counter = 0

        while counter < doc.css("h2:contains('Popular Electric Guitars')+div.overflowing-row_items    ul.tiles.tiles--single-row.tiles--grow.tiles--three-wide li.tiles_tile").length
        electric = {
            name: doc.css("h2:contains('Popular Electric Guitars')+div.overflowing-row_items ul.tiles.tiles--single-row.tiles--grow.tiles--three-wide li.tiles_tile")[counter].text,
            url: doc.css("h2:contains('Popular Electric Guitars')+div.overflowing-row_items ul.tiles.tiles--single-row.tiles--grow.tiles--three-wide li.tiles_tile a.marketing-callout__inner")[counter]["href"]
        }
        counter += 1
        electrics << electric
        end
        electrics
    end

    def self.get_acoustic
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://reverb.com/c/acoustic-guitars"))

        acoustics = []
        counter = 0

        while counter < doc.css("h2:contains('Popular in Acoustic Guitars')+div.overflowing-row_items ul.tiles.tiles--single-row.tiles--grow.tiles--three-wide li.tiles_tile").length
            acoustic = {
                name: doc.css("h2:contains('Popular in Acoustic Guitars')+div.overflowing-row_items ul.tiles.tiles--single-row.tiles--grow.tiles--three-wide li.tiles_tile")[counter].text,
                url: doc.css("h2:contains('Popular in Acoustic Guitars')+div.overflowing-row_items ul.tiles.tiles--single-row.tiles--grow.tiles--three-wide li.tiles_tile a.marketing-callout__inner")[counter]["href"]
            }
            counter += 1
            acoustics << acoustic
        end
        acoustics
    end
```

In my CLI class, when the user types in ‘electric’ or ‘acoustic’ they will get back the name and URL. Here’s one of the methods:

```
while (input = gets.strip.downcase) != 'exit'

            case input
            when "electric"
               electrics = HiStrung::Scraper.get_electric
               electrics.each do |electric|
                puts "#{electric.name}"
               end
```

When I put `.name`, I get:

```
/Users/tlreigns/RoyalTerminal/hi_strung/lib/hi_strung/cli.rb:43:in `block in menu': undefined method `name' for #<Hash:0x00007fab93b96a40> (NoMethodError)
```

but if i just do `#{electric}`, I get:

```
{:name=>"Fender Telecaster", :url=>"https://reverb.com/marketplace/electric-guitars?query=telecaster"}
{:name=>"Gibson Les Paul", :url=>"https://reverb.com/marketplace?query=les%20paul"}
{:name=>"Fender Stratocaster", :url=>"https://reverb.com/marketplace/electric-guitars?query=stratocaster"}
{:name=>"Gibson SG", :url=>"https://reverb.com/marketplace?query=sg"}
{:name=>"Fender Jazzmaster", :url=>"https://reverb.com/marketplace?query=jazzmaster"}
```

How do I get the name and URL separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of `electrics` is a hash. You only want the values instead of the key-value pairs.

So, I believe you just need

```
puts electric[:name]
```

and

```
puts electric[:url]
```

(without string interpolation will work as Amit Patel points out in the comments) to obtain the desired output.

Comment: Ahhh it worked, thank you! Haven't really worked with hashes so this a newbie for me! Appreciate it!!

Comment: String interpolation `"#{}"` is not required. `puts` can print any kind of object. So `puts electric[:url]` is enough for printing string.

Comment: @AmitPatel Ah, yep, of course you are right. I was just copying and modifying the OP's format without really thinking. Thanks!